# android facebook sdk setcaption not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to share a photo with caption and link from my android app to facebook, my photo is uploaded to facebook but caption is not updating Here is my code

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);
                SharePhoto sharePhoto1 = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                        .setBitmap(bitmap)
                        .setCaption("This is a Beautiful Picture")
                        .build();

                ShareContent shareContent = new ShareMediaContent.Builder()
                        .addMedium(sharePhoto1)
                        .setPageId("132583174018394")
                        .build();
                shareDialog.show(shareContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar and noticed that the setCaption() method did not work. Take a look at the android facebook sdk documentation in this link, and read the getCaption() method description:

"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/SharePhoto/"

"Gets the user generated caption. Note that the 'caption' must come from the user, as pre-filled content is forbidden by the Platform Policies (2.3)."